# Find the maximum number of primes that divide $n.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that their GCD has $5$ divisors, and their LCM has $30$ divisors. Find the maximum number of primes that divide $n.$

Here is my thought process:

So, the prime factorization of the GCD is $p^4$ and the prime factorization of the LCM is $a^1 b^2 c^4.$ Thus $m*n$ has to be $a^1 b^2 c^4 p^4. $

As $c$ and $p$ can't be different primes such that $\frac{a^1  b^2 c^4}{p^4}=$ integer, then $c$ and $p$ have to be the same prime.

Because $c$ and $p$ are the same prime, we can combine like terms and turn $m*n$ into $a^1  b^2 c^8,$ meaning that $n$ can be divisible by as many as $3$ primes.

Is this answer correct? If so, is there a more efficient way of completing this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your logic.

Comment: I apologize I had read [for my deleted answer] as *prime factors* and not divisors

Comment: No need to apologize, thanks to both of you for verifying the answer.